# while loop in while loop in bash script isn't properly highlighted in vim

Tags: bash, shell, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to write a while loop within one while loop in bash , the syntax of the second while doesn't get highlighted . Is there any special syntax for using this ?

```
while [ "ka" = $name ] 
do 
  while [ "ka" = $name ] //this while is not highlighted
  do
  done
done
```

Comment: R u referring to any editor like vi or vim?

Comment: Is it literally `$name]` or should it rather be `$name ]`? Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: its in vim editor and also the code doesn't get executed like intended.

Comment: @l0b0 It seems like the code doesn't behave like intended.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have already pointed out, this is a bug in the syntax plugin that affects non-Bash shell syntax.

Please submit a bug report (basically a link to this page) to the script's author, Charles Campbell; his email address is in the script's header; the script is located at `syntax/sh.vim` in the Vim install directory.

Should you not get a response, please inform the vim_dev mailing list (cp. http://www.vim.org/community.php; you need to register first) about this; hopefully, someone else will pick it up.

#### workaround

As a workaround, you could force Bash syntax by default (in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
:let g:is_bash      = 1
```

Comment: I was able to see the issue when I converted my file to use #!/bin/sh at the top as l0b0 pointed out.  And yes let g:is_bash = 1 also fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. For some reason it looks like **VIm 7.3 only highlights nested `while` commands if the shebang line points to `bash`.** For example, files starting with any of these are highlighted correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash
```

But not without a shebang line or with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
```

Test file:

```
[shebang line]
while true
do
    while true
    do
        while true
        do
            :
        done
    done
done
```

[`:set filetype?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779390/96588) prints `filetype=sh` in all cases, so it looks like it's a bug.

Comment: Good catch.  I normally just use #!/bin/bash and did not see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script. It works for me

```
#!/bin/bash
i="1"
while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
        j="1"
        while [ $j -lt 4 ]
        do
                echo $i
                j=$[$j+1]
        done
        i=$[$i+1]
done
```

It's output is

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

As expected.

The problem might be the code prior to the one you posted here, since I can't really find a syntax error in your code.