# vim indent html code inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, vim

here is an example of code inside of my .js file after gg=G command:

```
class ChannelSection extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <ChannelList channels={channels} />
            <ChannelForm />
            </div>
        )   
    }   
}
```

As you can see html tags have the same indent. I wish it would be like in html files - nested blocks indented further. Some plugin that can help?

Again, I need to indent ONLY HTML tags in .js file, not in .html file.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815548/how-do-i-tidy-up-an-html-files-indentation-in-vi

Comment: @MichaelHobbs , nope.

Comment: Your "JavaScript" is not "JavaScript" and your "HTML" is not HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [mxw/vim-jsx](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx). This plugin requires [pangloss/vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript), so you should install both of them.

This is a minimal `.vimrc` I used with vim-plug:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

call plug#begin()
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
call plug#end()

let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
```

Note that I set `g:jsx_ext_required` to `0` because you want to edit JSX tags in `.js` files.

Comment: Is this still the best answer in late 2020?

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods According to [mxw/vim-jsx](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx)'s README, [MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty](https://github.com/MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty) seems to be a next one. Personally, I use [sheerun/vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) for filetype support, and it uses MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty, too.

Answer (score 0):

Without plugins and just as a temporary quick solution, I [found the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114909/8958173) `:set filetype=html` (alias as `:set ft:html`) to be quite effective. This worked very well for me due to my work on HTML being minimal but persistent.

Indent the whole file via `gg=G` or selected section using just `=`.

Done. Now revert to the previous filetype (in your case, js) doing the reverse `:set ft=javascript` and continue as you were.

If you [didn't know your default filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779390/8958173) use `:set filetype?` before doing this.